Advice on data structure for an analysis and visualisation tool (javascript)
I am writing a browser-based tool to manipulate and visualise data (with D3.js). Currently, I store data in a JSON format, where each table is an object and columns are arrays. eg:
{
    "data": {
        "timeString": {
            "name": "time",
            "type": "time",
            "data": [
                "6/21/2024, 12:00:00 AM",
                "6/21/2024, 12:15:00 AM"
            ],
            "timeFormat": "M/D/YYYY hh:mm:ss AP",
            "timeMins": [
                "0.0000",
                "0.2500"
            ],
            "value0": {
                "name": "value0",
                "type": "value",
                "data": [
                    5,
                    1
                ],
                "value1": {
                    "name": "value1",
                    "type": "value",
                    "data": [
                        4,
                        2
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Because I want to manipulate the data, I have chosen to make a manipulated set also, eg:
{
    "data": {
        "timeString": {
            "name": "time",
            "type": "time",
            "data": [
                "6/21/2024, 12:00:00 AM",
                "6/21/2024, 12:15:00 AM"
            ],
            "timeFormat": "M/D/YYYY hh:mm:ss AP",
            "timeMins": [
                "0.0000",
                "0.2500"
            ],
            "value0": {
                "name": "value0",
                "type": "value",
                "data": [
                    5,
                    1
                ],
                "value1": {
                    "name": "value1",
                    "type": "value",
                    "data": [
                        4,
                        2
                    ],
                    "processSteps": [
                        {
                            "add": [
                                5
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "processedData": [
                        9,
                        7
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This is an overhead of memory, but improves performance. Likewise, for each graph, I have a similar pattern of data. This is another memory overhead, but improves performace.
Some of my datasets are now increasing in size to approx 50k rows. I've had to modify array functions (like Math.min(...arr)) because maximum call stack size errors crept in.
This has made me reconsider if my approach is the most efficient. I have thought about a single JSON, like:
{
    "data": {
        "names": [
            "time",
            "value0",
            "value1"
        ],
        "types": [
            "time",
            "value",
            "Value"
        ],
        "timeFormat": [
            "D/M/YYYY hh:mm:ss AP",
            -1,
            -1
        ],
        "data": [
            {
                "time": "6/21/2024, 12:00:00 AM",
                "timeMins": 0.0000,
                "value0": 5,
                "value1": 4
            },
            {
                "time": "6/21/2024, 12:15:00 AM",
                "timeMins": 0.2500,
                "value0": 1,
                "value1": 2
            }
        ],
        "processSteps": {
            "value0": [
                {
                    "add": [
                        5
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "processedData": [
            {
                "value0": 9
            },
            {
                "value0": 7
            }
        ]
    }
}

I've considered removing the duplicated, processed, data but haven't yet run into memory issues and the efficiency saving is large, given a visualisation re-render doesn't need to recalculate the processes.
I've thought about also using indexedDB, but that seems to add a layer of complexity for not much apparent gain.
Does anyone have advice on how best to architect the data for memory and performance in this use case?

I've autoformatted your examples, and the nesting is unusual - did you intend value0 to be a property of timeString and value2 to be a property of value0 rather than columns being at the same level?

One thing you don't yet seem to have considered is whether you gain anything by making it column oriented rather than row oriented. Usually this gives a performance gain, so your final data would look like:
{
    "data": {
        "names": [
            "time",
            "value0",
            "value1"
        ],
        "types": [
            "time",
            "value",
            "Value"
        ],
        "timeFormat": [
            "D/M/YYYY hh:mm:ss AP",
            -1,
            -1
        ],
        "data": {
            "time": [
                "6/21/2024, 12:00:00 AM",
                "6/21/2024, 12:15:00 AM"
            ],
            "timeMins": [
                0.0000,
                0.2500
            ],
            "value0": [
                5,
                1
            ],
            "value1": [
                4,
                2
            ]
        },
        "processSteps": {
            "value0": [
                {
                    "add": [
                        5
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "processedData": {
            "value0": [
                9,
                7
            ]
        }
    }
}

I'd also tend to do the opposite with the metadata, combine name/type/format into an object instead of splitting them into separate arrays.
{
    "data": {
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "time",
                "type": "time",
                "timeFormat": "D/M/YYYY hh:mm:ss AP"
            },
            {
                "name": "value0",
                "type": "value",
                "processSteps": [
                    {
                        "add": [
                            5
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "value1",
                "type": "value"
            }
        ],
        "data": {
            "time": [
                "6/21/2024, 12:00:00 AM",
                "6/21/2024, 12:15:00 AM"
            ],
            "timeMins": [
                0.0000,
                0.2500
            ],
            "value0": [
                5,
                1
            ],
            "value1": [
                4,
                2
            ]
        },
        "processedData": {
            "value0": [
                9,
                7
            ]
        }
    }
}

Though that is based on assumptions about how it gets processed by the client (field order matters, format ), which may be incorrect in your case - usually you want to get each field in turn, get the format and processing for that field, then can look up the data by field name. I would use null rather than  -1 for no value in either case.
